# C++ uniform_real_distribution keeps outputting the same values each time

Tags: c++, random, uniform-distribution, mt19937

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<double> res;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::mt19937 generator(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist01(0,1);

    int n = 100;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) res.push_back(dist01(generator));
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            cout << res[i] << " ";
            if (i%10==0) cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

So I have the program above. But the problem is every time i run, the result is the same, even though I have set `srand(time(NULL))`

What am I missing? How can I make the output random?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is working just fine and makes the output random every time... and you don't need `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: what?? On my computer (compiled on both codeblock + Qt Creator), the output is the same every time. How does this happen?

Comment: check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xptFFi). Refresh the page to see different output

Comment: Maybe your standard library has disfunctional `randomDevice`?